# Losing changes on push to Azure Mobile Apps database, in Java

Tags: java, azure-mobile-services

I've been developing an app using Android that makes use of the Mobile App Services that azure offer, to allow for offline sync to their nodeJS easytables.

I'm having a problem with their update methods. I understand that they update based on the id that a certain object has. I've updated one of my objects fields, with a new value, and I've passed it through to their update method, like so:

```
DataHolder.getInstance().InventoryTable.update(inventory).get();
```

DataHolder is just a singleton, that holds all of my tables for easy reference. I pass in my inventory object, after updating its location field, which is written as:

[image]

This updating doesn't seem to be a problem to me. The field updates, and when I close and open the app, as long as I'm offline, the changes stay.

The problem occurs when I try to sync the data back to the azure database, using the sync method:

```
syncContext.push().get();
DataHolder.getInstance().InventoryTable.pull(null).get();
```

The changes are lost, and it all reverts back to what is currently stored on the online database.

I have also tried with:

```
syncContext.push().get();
DataHolder.getInstance().InventoryTable.pull(null, "inventory").get();
```

In the case above, changes are not lost, but information still doesn't sync to the database.

I have made no changes to the easytables. They are using the default code that azure provides you with when you first create the tables.

I'm also unsure if I should mention that the updatedAt field doesn't change on my local database. I'm assuming that this is updated once that sync happens between the local and the online database.

I've read countless articles, and many questions on StackOverflow, but still nothing is solving this issue.
I'm unsure where I've gone wrong, so hopefully one of you can help me.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue this morning.
Yesterday, I had changed the online database, and removed a column. I didn't reflect this in the android application, so the SQLite Database was still being created with this column. As soon as I removed it, it started to sync correctly.

Comment: An alternative if you needed to support existing clients, would be to remove the property for the now-missing database column in the insert and update scripts for this table on your server.